Best Practices for Storing Keys and Public URLs in Expo React Native Project? How to make secrets environmental variable in expo?
I'm currently working on a React Native project using Expo and need guidance on securely storing keys and public URLs. I want to ensure that sensitive information is handled properly to maintain security.
Specific Issues:
I have two main concerns:

Storing public API URLs securely.
Managing sensitive information like keys in a safe and reliable
manner.

Current Approach:
Following the Expo documentation, I've stored public URLs in the .env file in the root folder using the format EXPO_PUBLIC_[NAME]=VALUE. Additionally, I've used the eas secret:create command to generate keys.
Actual vs. Expected Output:
When I list the secrets using eas secret:list, the output doesn't match what I expected based on the documentation. I'm seeing a different format, and I'm unsure if I'm following the correct procedure.
Request for Help:
What are the best practices for securely storing public API URLs in an Expo React Native project?
How should I manage sensitive information like keys to ensure security and reliability?
Can anyone provide guidance on interpreting the output of eas secret:list and ensuring it aligns with the expected format?
  # .env file
EXPO_PUBLIC_API_URL=https://example.com/api
CONSUMER_KEY=key_number
CONSUMER_SECRET=consumer_secrets

What I got:
eas secret:list
Secrets for this account and project:
ID          _id
Name        SECRET_NAME
Scope       project
Type        STRING
Updated at  Apr 23 17:32:46

What I expected:
eas secret:list
Secrets for this account and project:
┌────────────────┬────────┬─────────┬──────────────────────────────────────┬─────────────────┐
│ Name           │ Type   │ Scope   │ ID                                   │ Updated at      │
├────────────────┼────────┼─────────┼──────────────────────────────────────┼─────────────────┤
│ APP_UPLOAD_KEY │ string │ account │ 366bd434-b538-4192-887c-036c0eddedec │ Oct 05 11:51:46 │
├────────────────┼────────┼─────────┼──────────────────────────────────────┼─────────────────┤
│ NPM_TOKEN      │ string │ project │ 03f4881f-88fd-4d94-9e35-a5c34d39c2f2 │ Oct 05 11:51:33 │
├────────────────┼────────┼─────────┼──────────────────────────────────────┼─────────────────┤
│ SECRET_FILE    │ file   │ project │ 72c7ac1e-78d0-4fa2-b105-229260cecc88 │ Oct 05 11:52:12 │
├────────────────┼────────┼─────────┼──────────────────────────────────────┼─────────────────┤
│ sentryApiKey   │ string │ project │ 88dd0296-9119-4d50-a91b-1f646733f569 │ Oct 05 11:51:40 │
└────────────────┴────────┴─────────┴──────────────────────────────────────┴─────────────────┘

I appreciate any insights or recommendations on how to handle these aspects of Expo React Native development securely.

From the Expo docs, it's important to remember that nothing in your client-side code is "secret":

Always remember that anything that is included in your client side code should be considered public and readable to any individual that can run the application. EAS Secrets are intended to be used to provide values to an EAS Build job so that they may be used during the build process. Examples of correct usage include setting the NPM_TOKEN for installing private packages from npm, or a Sentry API key to create a release and upload your sourcemaps to their service. EAS Secrets do not provide any additional security for values that you end up embedding in your application itself, such as an AWS access key or other private keys.

Simply put, if someone has access to your compiled code, they can decompile it and get values or logic from it. That said, app identifiers necessary for authentication or to connect to your API are probably fine to leave in as part of the standard EXPO_PUBLIC_{variable_name} convention since they are required for operation and (hopefully) your infrastructure has measures in place to prevent abuse of them (For example, exchanging auth tokens to access data further). Things like 3rd party API keys (which may be rate limited, have billing tied to usage, etc.) should be stored server-side in a middleware API that you own and control; The client app then requests information from your server, which then uses those sensitives values on behalf of the client before returning the results, thus denying the end-user any access to those codes directly.
For output, if eas-cli is not behaving as expected, you can always check (and edit) values through the UI at https://expo.dev/accounts/{account-or-organization}/projects/{project-slug}/secrets. What your output is showing appears to match the format I see when I run the same against my project.
I'm no expert, so if you're dealing with especially sensitive info, consult with your infrastructure team or a networking professional with your specific scenario. You may also get help from the Expo team by asking on the Expo Developers discord. Good luck!
